# Azure Blob Storage Image URL? iOS

Tags: ios, azure-blob-storage

Im trying to retrieve the URL of a blob item in a container. Using Azure's [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage) I have successfully uploaded an image and retrieved the image as data but this is not ideal in my situation.

In Azure Storage Explorer there is in fact a url for each blob item in a container but I simply can't figure out how to get it in code.  Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of blob URLs? or just for a single item? Because either way, you could probably use the list blob and filter or sort the results you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs

Answer (score 2):

> In Azure Storage Explorer there is in fact a url for each blob item in a container but I simply can't figure out how to get it in code.

In fact, I am not very clear about what you want is listing blob url or getting the blob item. For both of them, you could use [Azure Storage Client Library for iOS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios) to achieve.

So, if you want to **[get the blob url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage#list-the-blobs-in-a-container)** in container, you could use a helper method to recursively call the list blobs method every time a continuation token is returned.

For a blob, the base URI includes the name of the account, the name of the container, and the name of the blob:

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
```

For example:

```
https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/container/a/b/c.txt
```

If you would **[get the blob item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage#download-a-blob)** in container, you could download a blob to a NSString object.

For more detailed description and code, you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage).

Answer (score 0):

```
let containerURL = "https://yourstoragename.blob.core.windows.net/\(ContainerName)\(SASToken)"  
var container : AZSCloudBlobContainer       
var error: NSError?       
container = AZSCloudBlobContainer(url: NSURL(string: containerURL)! as URL, error: &error)       
if ((error) != nil) {
        print("Error in creating blob container object.  Error code = %ld, error domain = %@, error userInfo = %@", error!.code, error!.domain, error!.userInfo);
    }        
else {        
   let blob = container.blockBlobReference(fromName: "Image.png") 
    blob.downloadToFile(withPath: fromfile, append: true, completionHandler:{(NSError) -> Void in
                var blobUrl = blob.storageUri.primaryUri               
    })
}
```